# How to get categories list for multiple stores on same page?

Tags: magento-1.7, navigation

I have a website which is separated into two stores: Mens and Womens. I am trying to list the categories of both stores in the footer template which is shared by both sites.

Ideally I would have:

MENS

- -MensCat1
- -MensCat2
- -MensCat3
- -MensCat4

WOMENS

- -WomensCat1
- -WomensCat2
- -WomensCat3
- -WomensCat4

etc.

I can pull the categories of a particular store with the following:

```
$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(306)->getChildrenCategories();
                foreach($children as $child){
                    echo $child->getName() . " " . $child->getUrl() . "<br/>";
                }
```

where 306 is the id of the Mens Root Category.

That will give me

- -MensCat1
- -MensCat2
- -MensCat3
- -MensCat4

The problem is the URLs will be http://{{base_url}}/womens/MensCat1 if I am in the womens store.

Is there a better way to do this so that the URLs are relative to the stores they belong to, or to force the store url to change in the getUrl request?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the base url from another store there are, as far as I can see, 2 options.

**Build the url yourself:** building the links yourself by retrieving a specific Store's url and prepending it

```
$base_url = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);
```

And then concatenating the category URL to it.

[EDIT: second solution is better (don't use first)]

**Store emulation:**
Run a part of your code emulated under the mensstore to retrieve the right categories and URL's

```
$appEmulation = Mage::getSingleton('core/app_emulation');
$store_id = 1; // The ID if your men store
$initialEnvironmentInfo = $appEmulation->startEnvironmentEmulation($store_id);

$children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(306)->getChildrenCategories();
foreach($children as $child){
   echo $child->getName() . " " . $child->getUrl() . "<br/>";
}

$appEmulation->stopEnvironmentEmulation($initialEnvironmentInfo);
```

Comment: +1 for the store emulation approach. I would not recommend building the links manually. You might get in trouble. What if a category url is not indexed?

Comment: I agree, the second approach is probably better. I'm not sure if it's acceptable performance wise since you're loading a whole store just for some links.

Comment: I don't think it's that harmful. Anyway...for the first approach you still load a store :)

Comment: oh shoot, you're right. ok made an edit to point out the second is better ^^

Comment: Hi Sander, thanks for your suggestions. I can't get Method 2 to work for me. It keeps returning the /womens/ url when in the womens store and vice versa. I'm using hard coded ids for mens root category and mens store id but the URLs still show the current store.

Comment: I might just add that I have the config setting '
Add Store Code to Urls' set to Yes for SEO purposes. I'm not sure if this would affect it, I would have thought emulating the other store would be OK but it may cause the issue?