# Category url always has wrong store in path

Tags: url, overrides, category

How can i get a category url rewritten for a specific store in magento?

I have 2 stores: us and uk.

Store codes:  en_gb and en_us.

If i load a category in code

```
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(3);  // 3 is the uk store
$categoryUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($store->getRootCategoryId())->setStoreId($store->getId());
```

The url that comes back always has the default website code in the path i.e. and also never the seo friendly url.  It is the `category/view` url

```
http://mysite/us/catalog/category/view/ukbase/id/3
```

EDIT:

By setting the store in the script the correct country is added to the url:

```
 Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
```

Why is this needed?

Also it still doesnt give the seo friendly url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento uses the current store to build the full category url so setting the current store will force it to use the right base URL.

A [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/8512/how-to-get-categories-list-for-multiple-stores-on-same-page/) posted earlier today might give some more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using the getUrlModel method below:

```
$store_code = 'something';
$store_id = 2;
$category_id = 234;
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->setStoreId($store_id)->load($category_id);

$url = $category->getUrlModel()
    ->getUrlInstance()
    ->getDirectUrl($requestPath, array("_store"=>$store_code, "_nosid"=>true));
```